# Add Closure action on a UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, closures, uilabel, uigesturerecognizer

I want to add a closure when user tap a UILabel:

```
class ActionLabel: UILabel {
    typealias DidTapLabel = (ActionLabel) -> ()

    private let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didTouchUpInside(sender:)))

    var didTouchUpInside: DidTapLabel? {
        didSet {
            if didTouchUpInside != nil {
                self.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
                self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            } else {
                self.removeGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
                self.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
            }
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Actions
    @objc func didTouchUpInside(sender: ActionLabel) {
        if let handler = didTouchUpInside {
            handler(self)
        }
    }
}
```

usage:

```
    label.didTouchUpInside = { [weak self] sender in
        guard let strongSelf = self else {return}
        print(strongSelf)
    }
```

but does not seem to work

Answer (score 3):

You cannot initialize the gesture recognizer with a reference to self because the initialization is not completed at that point. Printing the gesture recognizer array reveals the information that the `target` is not set

```
addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
print("\(gestureRecognizers)")
```

Output (Look at the end of the line)

```
Optional([<UITapGestureRecognizer: 0x6000001f9600; state = Possible; view = <asdfefe.ActionLabel 0x7fd714a03ea0>; target= <(action=didTouchUpInside:, target=<(null) 0x0>)>>])
```

So, to solve this you initialize the gesture recognizer in a init call

```
private var tapGestureRecognizer:UITapGestureRecognizer!

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didTouchUpInside))
}
```

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 2):

The reason why Your code doesn't work is:

```
private let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(touchAction))
```

**tartget: self** is the point, when the ActionLabel is initialized, It will load your local **Variable or Constant** first, so you will get a null target, because self is not initialized now, and it will not call the touch action when you tap your view.

**The Good Solution is:**

```
var didTouchUpInside: DidTapLabel? {
    didSet {
        if didTouchUpInside != nil {
            self.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(touchAction)))
            self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        } else {
            if let tapGestureRecognizer = self.gestureRecognizers?[0] as? UITapGestureRecognizer {
                self.removeGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
            }
            self.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        }
    }
}
```